# use query string in ajax function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a simple AJAX function to send data from query string, and the append the DIV. .I have tried a variety of different methods, but none that will updat the div. If it updates, it returns NULL, otherwise it just goes to the request.php page. If I move the prevent default function under the click event, it does nothing.
Any help would be appreciated!!  TIA

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $("#link").click(function(e)
    {

        $.ajax(
                {
                    type    : "GET",
                    url     : "request.php",
                    data    : { id: link.attr('id') },
                    success : function(response)
                    {
                        $("#ajaxresponse    div").fadeOut("fast", function()
                        {
                            $("#ajaxresponse div").remove();
                            $("#ajaxresponse").append($(response).hide().fadeIn());
                        });

                    }
                });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

</script>
</head><body>
<h1>
    AJAX with PHP
</h1>
<div class="content">

<a href="request.php?id=1" id="link" data-id="1" >Submit Link</a>

</div>
<div id="ajaxresponse">
    <div>please submit the form</div>
</div>
```

The request.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['id'];


echo getTemplate($username);

function getTemplate($username)
{
return '<div class="box">
    <h1>The ID is</h1>
    <div class="meta">username: '.$username.'</div>
</div>';

}

?>
```

Comment: What is the data if you access the url directly, and what is in `response`

Comment: I am just trying to send the "1" at the end of the url: request.php?id=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to read the id value of the link being clicked in a wrong way. This should work.

```
$(function()
{
    $("#link").click(function(e)
    {
       var link=$(this);
       e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type    : "GET",
                    url     : "request.php",
                    data    : { id: link.attr('id') },
                    success : function(response)
                    {
                        $("#ajaxresponse div").fadeOut("fast", function()
                        {
                            $("#ajaxresponse div").html(response).fadeIn();
                        });

                    }
                });   

    });
});
```

You can even use the `get` method which is a short version of jQuery ajax call with method type as `GET`.

```
$(function()
{
    $("#link").click(function(e)
    {
       var link=$(this);
       e.preventDefault();
       $.get("request.php?id="+link.attr('id'),function(response){
               $("#ajaxresponse div").fadeOut("fast", function()
               {
                     $("#ajaxresponse div").html(response).fadeIn();
               });   
       });             
    });
});
```

Comment: I am just trying to send the "1" at the end of the url: request.php?id=1...there is prob a better way, Im just new :)

Comment: @Jjames: There is no problem in that.

Comment: When I run it, I get back "link", the ID of the anchor tag, instead of the 1 on the query string

Comment: I got it...just had to change the link.attr  to   link.data....probably my crappy question phrasing :)...thanks a bunch!!!